# How do I pass a local variable to remote PowerShell Script

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

Let me brief out what all methods I tried.

Here is the Start_TestTalk.ps1 script

`$RN = $env:RName
$TestV = "Local_Variable"
Write-Host $TestV
Write-Host $RName
Write-Host $RN
Write-Host $env:RName`

I've declared the below variables

`$Name="myname"
$CPU= 100`

**First Method:**

`PS C:\Users\Administrator> Invoke-Command -Session $s -Scriptblock{ & "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Start_TestTalk.ps1
" -RName $args[0] -RCPU $args[1]}-argumentlist $Name,$CPU
Local_Variable`

**Second Method**

`PS C:\Users\Administrator> Invoke-Command -Session $s -Scriptblock{ & "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Start_TestTalk.ps1
" -RName $using:Name -RCPU $using:CPU}
Local_Variable`

**Third Method**

`PS C:\Users\Administrator> Invoke-Command -Session $s -Scriptblock{ Param($Name, $CPU) & "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop
\Start_TestTalk.ps1" -RName $Name -RCPU $CPU}-argumentlist $Name ,$CPU
Local_Variable`

All the above three methods just prints the 'Local_Variable' which is local to the remote machine and doesn't print the variable that I pass from my local machine(here $Name).

Comment: What is the contents of `Test.ps1`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: Thanks, there's nothing much as of now for testing purposes, I'm just trying to print the variable I pass from source machine. Here is the simple code

$RN = $env:RName
$TestV = "Local_Variable"
Write-Host $TestV
Write-Host $RName
Write-Host $RN
Write-Host $env:RName

Comment: The start_testtalk.ps1 doesn't use parameters....

Comment: @MartinBrandl: Sorry, I didn't get what you meant by 'start_testtalk.ps1 doesn't use parameters'.

Comment: You are passing parameters to Start-TestTalk.ps1 but the script is missing the parameter section e. g. `param($Name, $CPU)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the way on how this feature works with the help of a Senior Architect here in our company. The variables sent from the local(source machine) are not actually made local on the remote machine and these just get dumped as values on the remote machine and not as variables(you can't use variables). A simple example on how the above script which I had mentioned works

**Start_TestTalk.ps1 script**

`$RN = $args[0]
    $CPU= $args[1]
    Write-Host $RN
    Write-Host $CPU`

Now use the same old Invoke Command with slight changes removing the variables earlier used to hold the values from local machine

**Invoking the remote script using argument list**

`I've declared the below variables
    $Name="myname"
    $CPU= 100
    PS C:\Users\Administrator\ Invoke-Command -Session $s -Scriptblock{ &
    "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Start_TestTalk.ps1" $args[0] $args[1] }-
    argumentlist $Name,$CPU
   myname
   100`

Now you see that you get the required output on the remote machine, so it conveys that the values are directly getting dumped and not with the variables and hence I was earlier not able to use those variables on the remote machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:using` variable prefix:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $s -Scriptblock{ & "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Test.ps1" -RName $using:Name -RCPU $using:CPU}
```

Comment: Thank you, It's still the same even with 'using' variable prefix
PS > Invoke-Command -Session $s -Scriptblock{ & "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Test.ps1
" -RName $using:Name -RCPU $using:CPU}
Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Name'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or
empty, and then try the command again.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-Process], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetProcessCommand

Comment: Then you probably use PowerShell 2.0? Try this: `Invoke-Command -Session $s -Scriptblock{ Param($Name, $CPU) & "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Test.ps1" -RName $Name -RCPU $CPU}-argumentlist $Name ,$CPU`

Comment: I'm using the Powershell version 4 on both the local and remote machines, I tried the method you suggested as well but still the same. I've also updated the question with more specific details to avoid confusion. Thanks.